# Odoo Survey : How to fill survey partially at one stage and other remaining at other stage

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, survey

I have a wizard in CRM, that wizard will have a **many2one field of survey.survey**.

There are four stages in crm.lead

In one stage, I will select that many2one field of survey and fill some details, I will move to other stage. I have to fill the rest of the survey that is partially filled in the earlier stage.

Any solutions?